# Requests get stuck with mod_mono

Tags: apache, mono, mod-mono

The same question I have has been asked on the mono mailing list 3 years ago, so I will shamelessly copy / paste from the mailing list (no answers there) :

My problem is, that a lot of requests appear to get stuck somewhere in between
apache and the mod-mono-server. I activated the mod_mono control panel and I see
an ever growing list of requests there, which never get processed:

```
Restart Server
Stop Accepting Requests
6 requests served; limit: 10000
38 requests currently being processed; limit: unlimited; total: 3679  

    1363 661s /myservice/users/3606/items/4
    247 945s /myservice/items/2/data
    2350 424s /myservice/items/4/data
    1237 692s /myservice/items/3/data
    ....
```

Most requests do get processed, but the list with the dead requests is always
growing until I restart apache.

Using the "restart server" from the control panel do nothing except reseting the  count of requests served.

Any idea : 
=> what can cause a request to get stuck ? 
=> How to kill them, individually or as a whole ?

OS :  Debian 3.16.51-2
Apache : 2.4.25
Mono : Mono JIT compiler version 5.18.0.268

Thanks.

Comment: don't use mod_mono, it's unmaintained, use ASP.NET Core

Comment: @knocte if i'm not mistaken, .Net Core isn't compatible with most 3rd party librairies.

Comment: what? most 3rd party libraries are published in .NETStandard format nowadays, which makes them compatible with .NET Core